# Can't Install VSFTPD on CentOS 7 - "No package vsftpd available"

Tags: centos7, vsftpd

Hi i want to install VSFTPD on my CentOS 7 server but it could not find the package and says "No package vsftpd available". Do i need to add another repo or do you know how to figure out this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No special repos required.

It's enough to:
`yum update`
`yum install vsftpd`

You may want to update cache with:
`yum makecache`

Comment: @Hardoman hi, thanks for your message. I already updated the cache and yum bu no lucks. Looks like a strange problem. I could not find related topics on forums and sites either. Maybe its time to say goodbye to CentOS.

Comment: i am unfamiliar with the repo system of redhead based systems, but on debian you need a sub repository (main is always there, but cobtrib and non-free not) remind that makecwche might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

After running `yum update` to make sure your system is up to date, `yum install vsftpd` should work and install VSFTPD.

To be on the safe side, I ran `repoquery` and verified this package came from the following repository (configured under `/etc/yum.repos.d/`):

```
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```